# UICollectionCellView - Bringing repeated Images

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, parse-platform

I am downloading some images from parse to a `UICollectionView`. The problem is that the cells are being reused before the images are downloaded. How can I cancel the request and avoid repeating the same images on different cells?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    WallImage *wallImageFromUser = [DataStore instance].wallImagesFromUser[indexPath.row];

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UserPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (UserPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([[DataStore instance].wallImagesFromUser count] > 0) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
            UIImage *postedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[wallImageFromUser.imageFile getData]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [cell.userPhotoButton setImage:postedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            });
        });
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I have tried to use `[wallImagesFromUser.imageFile cancel]` but with no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

According to me you should create your cell identifier name as your customcell name. it is better approach to avoid repeating of cell in your app. and try to this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"UserPhotoCollectionViewCell";
UserPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (UserPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
        WallImage *wallImageFromUser = [DataStore instance].wallImagesFromUser[indexPath.row];
        UIImage *postedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[wallImageFromUser.imageFile getData]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [cell.userPhotoButton setImage:postedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });
    });
return cell;
}
```

but i prefer SDWebImage to download image in cell of collectionview/tableview
you can use SDWebImage third party to download image in your collectionview cell's image. it download image once and set image to that particular cell. it reduce the problem of repeating image in collectionview cell. it improve your app performance also. you can download here

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Sorry but I reckon you are mistaken. You have to use dequeReusable for cells. And I am downloading the images from Parse web server.

Comment: you are right. i have forgotten to add dequeReusable for cells.thanks